# Is .contiguous().flatten() the same as .view(-1) in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

Are these exactly the same?

```
myTensor.contiguous().flatten()
myTensor.view(-1)
```

Will they return the same auto grad function etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not exactly the same.

- `myTensor.contiguous().flatten()`:

Here, [`contiguous()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.contiguous) either returns a copy of `myTensor` stored in contiguous memory, or returns `myTensor` itself if it is already contiguous. Then, [`flatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html#torch.flatten) reshapes the tensor to a single dimension. However, the returned tensor could be the same object as `myTensor`, a view, or a copy, so the contiguity of the output is not guaranteed.

Relevant [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_view.html):

> It’s also worth mentioning a few ops with special behaviors:
>
> - reshape(), reshape_as() and flatten() can return either a view or new tensor, user code shouldn’t rely on whether it’s view or not.
> - contiguous() returns itself if input tensor is already contiguous, otherwise it returns a new contiguous tensor by copying data.

- `myTensor.view(-1)`:

Here, [`view()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) returns a tensor with the same data as `myTensor`, and will only work if `myTensor` is already contiguous. The result [may not be contiguous](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_view.html) depending on the shape of `myTensor`.

Answer (score 1):

Some illustration:

```
xxx = torch.tensor([[1], [2], [3]])
xxx = xxx.expand(3, 4)
print ( xxx )
print ( xxx.contiguous().flatten() )
print ( xxx.view(-1) )


tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]])
tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-281fe94f55fb> in <module>
      3 print ( xxx )
      4 print ( xxx.contiguous().flatten() )
----> 5 print ( xxx.view(-1) )

RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.
```